# How to put a href in each img inside a div (slideshow Jquery)

Tags: jquery, slideshow, href

I got a Jquery Slideshow from http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow
everything is working fine. I want to put a hyperlink for each picture inside the div, but when I put ahrefs inside it, it only displays the first picture and not the other pictures.

The sample is inside the link:http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

NOTE:I want Different Links for every picture in the slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

-----change in js----

```
    var $active = $('#slideshow a.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow a:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow a:first');
```

------change is css-------

```
/*** set the width and height to match your images **/

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow a.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow a.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

</style>
```

---change in html---

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <a href="#"> <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" /></a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" /></a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude it's working, but there's a delay in the first picture 5s.
But thanks anyways.

Comment: @Minato Arisato Please consider green-checking this answer if it helpful for you.

Comment: @Minato Arisato put class="active" to your first a tag like this :- <a href="#" class="active"> <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1"  /></a> then your problem of delay solve.

Comment: oh thanks dude and already checked this as the great answer.
btw can't vote it up just recently created a account XD.

Comment: Harshit Tailor, can ya help me one more time? I need to center the slideshow but everytime I tinker with the CSS positions or the cell spacing, either it's not working or it goes down and then the other picture goes away.. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

```
var images = $('#slideshow').children('img');
$.each(images,function(){
   images.wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
});
```

NOTE: Haven't tried this code myself. Sorry.

Comment: I want a different link for every picture sorry if I didn't state it earlier.